# Java: Check if a generic is an int

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

```
public class Hashing<Key, Elem>
```

I want to check if Key is an int, so I place this lines in the constructor:

```
Key key = null;
if (!(key instanceof Integer)) {
    throw new TypeOfKeyStillNotSupportedException();
}
```

However, I create one this way:

```
tHash = new Hashing<Integer, Movie>(max);
```

And the damn TypeOfKeyStillNotSupportedException() pops. Why is this happening and how can I do it properly?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Already found that the problem is with key being assigned null. The question is now: How to do the check?

Comment: Key is the generic. The constructor is nothing else than that check at all, and the class declaration is as the first line, nothing else.

Comment: Show the method that surrounds the `if` block that does the `instanceof` so we can get your intention of **why** you need to do this check.

Comment: It's the constructor, the constructor has to check that the Key is a valid type. Read the answer to your comment on your answer :)

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc - I think you've got the wrong idea of the purpose of homework.  The purpose is not to get the right answer.  The purpose is for you to LEARN.  When someone gives you an answer, you need to THINK about the answer they have given and how to apply it.  If you just copy and paste it without any thought, you won't learn a thing from it.

Comment: When did you see me do such thing? If you mean John's answer, well, I understood that both ways are equivalent, but since the first one already didn't work, what was I supposed to tell him a part from "ok, so what, it still doesn't works"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java generics are implemented using [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): the generic information is discarded by the compiler after being used for type checking, so at runtime your class is effectively just `Hashing<Object, Object>`.  That's why you can't do runtime checks based on a generic type.

You can add an argument of type `Class<Key>` to the constructor, and the caller will have to pass the correct class object for the type being used as the key.  For example, in a `Hashing<Integer, String>`, only `Integer.class` will be accepted as the value of that argument, and you can use that for runtime type checking.  The requirement to pass a the key's class object as a parameter makes the constructor call look a little awkward, though.

Comment: The fact is that this is homework, and the specification of that class is immutable. I only get Hashing<Key, Elem>, and I need to know if Key is Integer at runtime.

Comment: You could use `instanceof` in some other method that has an *actual* key parameter passed by the caller.  But you can't do it without a real key to examine.

Comment: That's exactly the way I had it at first. The problem is that the exception doesn't come out until an operation is actually done with the class, which allows the user to change things with an invalid Key, little long history. Resumed, I need to know it from the beginning.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't; the information isn't available.  It's the same bytecode no matter what type the caller wants to use, and everything that says `Key` in the source code is really just `Object` at runtime, and the constructor has no way to predict what kind of `Object` will be passed to other methods in the future.

Comment: But the constructor doesn't have to predict it. When the constructor is called, the generic has already been passed, hasn't it?

Comment: No, that's the point I'm trying to make:  generic type parameters *aren't* passed to methods at runtime.  They let the *compiler* check that you're not trying to do something nonsensical like pass a `String` to the `add()` method of a `List<Integer>`, but they have no effect on the compiled output.  You get the same bytecode as if you didn't use generics at all.

Answer (score 3):

`null` is not an `instanceof` anything. Due to type erasure, there's no way to check the type of `Key` directly at runtime. One option is to make the user pass in `Class<Key>` to the constructor so that you can check that:

```
public Hashing(Class<Key> keyType, ...) {
  if (keyType != Integer.class) {
    throw new TypeOfKeyStillNotSupportedException();
  }
  ...
}

...

Hashing<Integer, Foo> hashing = new Hashing<Integer, Foo>(Integer.class, ...);
```

To save yourself from having to repeat the type arguments, you can create a static factory method:

```
public static <K, E> Hashing<K, E> create(Class<K> keyType, ...) {
  return new Hashing<K, E>(keyType, ...);
}

...

Hashing<Integer, Foo> hashing = Hashing.create(Integer.class, ...);
```

Comment: Uh, I see. Then, how to do the check?

Comment: The instanceof operator is used to check for type of reference. The details can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html . Hope it helps :)

Comment: The fact is that this is homework, and the specification of that class is immutable. I only get Hashing<Key, Elem>, and I need to know if Key is Integer at runtime.

Comment: To know that it is an Integer during Runtime, you need not check at all. Let the VM do the checking for you :) See my answer for the full example text. Cheers!

Comment: I can't change the constructor. It's given in the specification :S

Answer (score 2):

If your code has "key = null;" right before the test of instanceof, then the Exception will necessarily be thrown.

The reason being that the instancof operator checks the reference of the type of object being pointed to and not how it is declared to be.

You can try with this simple example and remove the comments accordingly to see the difference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Object obj = new Integer(9);
    Object obj = null;

    if (!(obj instanceof Integer))
        System.out.println("Not Integer.");
    else
        System.out.println("Is Integer");
}
```

Also, you can find out more details here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Hope it helps :)

---

Full blown example of Java Generics:

```
class GenTest<Key extends Integer, Value>{
    Key key;
    Value val;

    GenTest(Key key, Value val){
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;

        System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + val);
    }
}

public class GenericRecap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Object obj = new Integer(9);
        Object obj = null;

        if (!(obj instanceof Integer))
            System.out.println("Not Integer.");
        else
            System.out.println("Is Integer");

        new GenTest<Integer, String>(9, "nine");
    //new GenTest<String, String>("funny", "nine");  // In-Error
    }
}
```

Also note that by having 'Key extends Integer', an exception will be thrown during Runtime if you pass that does not subclass Integer. Furthermore, if you're using and IDE that checks for it, it'll be flag as 'Type not within bound' of the GenTest Class.

Floats and Integer all inherit from Number. Thus you can 'extend Number' and then check for 'instanceof Integer' or 'instanceof Float' depending on how you want to use it in your code.

Hope it helps :) Cheers!

Comment: Ok. But if I don't initialize it to null, the compiler says that I have to initialize it. And I can't assign it any value because it's a generic!

How can I do this check then?

Comment: assigning values has nothing to do with it being `Generic`, I don't think you understand what `Generic` does

Comment: I see your point. I assigned it null just because the IDE forced me to do it. If that approach is not valid at all in your opinion, what's the proper way to check if the Generic that has been passed is an int?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "I assigned it null just because the IDE forced me to do it." See above, I have posted a full blown example. Cheers !

Comment: I meant that the IDE forced me to assign it null because it wouldn't allow me to use instanceof otherwise, I already understand why now. The "extends Integer" solution works, but, what if I need to check if it's, let's say an Integer or a Float?

Comment: The IDE "forces" you to initialize it and not force it to be set to null. This means that before you check an instancof variable, it is necessary to initialize it. To address the issue of Integers or Floats, they are all inherited from number, thus you need to 'extend Number' and then check 'instanceof Integer' or 'instanceof Float' depending on how you use it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Given the following from your example:

```
public class Hashing<K, E>
```

This makes no sense: because `K` is a `Type` that can be set to anything when the class is specialized. I changed the name from `Key` to `K` to remove confusion that you might have that `Key` isn't representing a `Type`. The general standard for `Type` names is to use single characters most of the time.

```
K key = null;
if (!(key instanceof Integer)) 
{
    throw new TypeOfKeyStillNotSupportedException();
}
```

if you change it to

```
K key = null;
if (!(key instanceof K)) 
{
    throw new TypeOfKeyStillNotSupportedException();
}
```

that would be a more `Generic` solution, but that doesn't make sense either because `key` will **always** be a type of `K`

`key` can't be `null` because `null` is not of any `Type`

Without having more context to what surrounds the `instanceof` check I don't know what your intention is.

Checking the `Type` of a `Generic` with `instanceof` is a code smell, and probably the wrong approach regardless.

Look here at how the `java.util.HashMap` [implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html) handles this problem.

There is only two places where they use `instanceof` and those are both legacy methods that accept only `Object` and are not typesafe.

Comment: I know it doesn't make much sense. The fact is that we are doing a Hash Table as homework. I initially wanted to obtain a Hash from whatever Object i got passed as Key, but the teacher told us to implement only an Integer hash function. I told him that it didn't make sense to use Key as generic if Key could only be an Integer, but he answered that I could Imagine that other type of Keys could be supported in the future, but that only Integers for the moment. Hope that clarified it all. One way or another, I always end up having to explain my whole life here :D

Comment: every object in Java has the `.hashCode()` function, which returns an `int`, you don't need to test `Type` to call `.hashCode()` on whatever `Type` that `Key` happens to be. I don't think he clearly communicated his intention when he said "only an Integer hash function", does he want you to write the hash calcuation or use only `int`, as in the primitive number as the hash data? You should clarify the `Integer` vs `int`eger requirement.

Comment: Both. I need to implement a hash function that takes an int and returns another. I thought of overriding .hashcode(), but the hash function is also given in the specifications...

Comment: I know, but my point is that the specifications of the teacher specify that there must be a "hash(Int i)" function that is used for calculating the hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

The way to deal with this is to **explicitly** test for null; e.g.

```
Key key = null;
if (key == null) {
    throw new KeyIsNullException();
} else if (!(key instanceof Integer)) {
    throw new TypeOfKeyStillNotSupportedException();
}

// ... or (for the literal minded) ...

if (key != null && !(key instanceof Integer)) {
    throw new TypeOfKeyStillNotSupportedException();
}
```

---

For the record, those people who responded that this was something to do with type erasure are off base.  You would get exactly the same behaviour if `Key` was a definite class or interface.

(On the other hand, if the code had said `someObj instanceof Key` ... that would be a compilation error because of the type erasure issue.)

Comment: Yeah, great, and now KeyIsNullException will come out, won't it? I need to know if the generic passed is an Integer, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [isInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) method which is the **dynamic** equivalent of `instanceof` operator.

For example,

```
Integer.class.isInstance(1); //return true
Integer.class.isInstance(null); //return false
```

**Edit**:
If you want to test against different class type, write a utility method like this:

```
static <T> boolean isInstance(Class<T> type, Object obj) {
    return type.isInstance(obj);
}
```

For example,

```
Hashing.<String>isInstance(String.class, "hi"); // return true
```

Comment: Makes no difference. `Xyz.class.isInstance(obj)` gives the same result as `obj instanceof Xyz`, even in the case where `obj` is `null`.